# Есть QScrollArea и нем QLabel. Как прокручиваться вниз при добавлении текста в QLabel?

Tags: qlabel, qscrollarea

Непонятно пока как прокручивать автоматически вниз, чтобы видна всегда была последняя информация (которая добавляется в конец QLabel)

(Qt 4.8.1 msvc-2010 если что)

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить: А просто readonly QTextEdit нельзя? Зачем такие сложности? Вопрос про устаревшую библиотеку оставим за скобками, сейчас в линухах поддерживается от 5.12.3...

Comment: Можно QTextEdit, но хочется QLabel (с html разметкой)

Comment: спрошу без обиняков: Qt 4.x - старая как отходы мамонта. QTextEdit - поддерживает HTML-тэги см. сюда :https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#details Есть ли какие-либо веские причины использования устаревшей библиотеки и заморачивания с компонентами, требуемые возможности которых реализованы в одном другом?

Comment: Не горячитесь, ничего там качественно нового в Qt5,6 нет. Отходы мамонта переживут нас всех.

Comment: Ну, раз детализировать задачу нет возможности - удачи в поисках решения! )))

Comment: На самом не чего детализировать-то, все банально оказалось. Надо сигнал вертикального слайдера changeRange(int min, int max) (как-то так вроде называется) связать со слотом и в слоте сделать setValue(max) для того же вертикального слайдера. И все...

Comment: Вот так подойдет:

`_CONNECT_( ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL( rangeChanged(int,int) ),  
               this, SLOT(slot_rangeChanged(int,int)));  


void Smart_Process_Dlg2::slot_rangeChanged(int min ,int max){  
    if( max >0 )  
        ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue( max );  
}  `